# I got problem sending FormData from my ReactNative app with Axios and get it in my server with multer

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, multer, form-data

i am using axios and FormData to send my files from client to server, on the server i am using multer for handling the datas,
my client's code for sending is like:
the file's title(the first field of append) for pdf and image are the same as server,
[image]
and when i send data on the server after multer that append a files to req, i am not able to get the files and its always undefined , the server code's looking like:
[image]
and the body of the request after requesting to server is like :
[image]

and headers of the request in the backend is :[image]
and my form data before sending looks like:[image]
I also tried these for FormData:

```
bodyFormData.append('pdfFile',pdfDetail.filepath,pdfDetail.filename)

bodyFormData.append('imageFile',{uri:coverDetails.filepath,name:coverDetails.filename,type:coverDetails.filetype})
```

How can I solve this? Thank you guys

Comment: did you tried `req.file.originalname.trim()`?

Comment: there is no file ! because there is problem sending from client and multer is not able to add .file to to req and send it to the controller

Comment: I am able to have the sent file in body ,idk what is the reason

Comment: try to put multipart form data in your header `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`, or check if its sended as it

Comment: I tested it before no difference

Comment: can you show us the request header of the axios request?

Comment: I updated the question and add the headers

Comment: could you show us the middleware where you put multer inbetween

Comment: router.post('/uploadANewBook',cpUpload,userController.uploadANewBook);

Comment: var cpUpload = multer({ storage : storage }).fields([{ name: 'pdfFile', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'imageFile', maxCount: 1 }])

Answer (score -1):

you need to specify content-type for axios requests.

try this:

```
axios({
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'uploadANewBook',
 data: bodyFormData,
 headers: {
  'x-access-token': token,
  'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
 }
```

Comment: but in the axios doc they mentioned we should avoid using content-type, if you send FormData it will automatically understand it is a form-data. I also test it too